# How to find points, sort them based on closeness, and get 1-20, 21-40, etc. Efficiently using Myisam and mysql and spatial index

Tags: mysql, sql, geospatial, myisam, spatial-index

Say I want to find 20 closest business near me. Latter I want to see the next 20 closest, etc. Yes I have myisam. I have spatial indexes on the point. I am looking for actual SQL command I should send.

To make it clear:

**Note:**

1. I am using **mysql myisam** spatial index. I surf google back and fro and found nothing about my exact need.
2. I do not want to compute
       distance for the whole table (that's too inefficient). The whole point of spatial index is that at least you can get rid a lot of points efficiently. If some points to your left and up do not qualify, then all points to the left and up of that point wouldn't qualify either.
3. I do not want to compute distance for
           any region which are still inefficient. My region of interest is 10km and there are 65k businesses there.
4. I do not mind computing distance
               for reasonable number of points because I want to sort the points by
               distance and be able to display point 1-20, 21-40, 41-60, etc.
5. I found a way to do so for postgis http://blog.opengeo.org/2011/09/28/indexed-nearest-neighbour-search-in-postgis/ I want something similar but for mysql myisam.
6. I want a website with actual sql code as sample or actual sample sql command. So please don't just say, "use spatial." Duh. I know. I want the actual sql command.
7. I do not want to do complicated loop of searching a small region first. There has to be an sql command that'll do this in one stroke efficiently done by mysql engine.
8. Cartesian distance is fine. No need to know that we live in a globe unless you're in northern or southern pole, which is not where most of our customers are.

There are 1.6 million bizs. Of course it's stupid to compute distance for all of them and then sort it.

That's where geo spatial index kicks in right?

So what SQL command I need to send?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I can't comment on your question, I guess I'm going to have to leave this as an answer.

Look at this question:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22082/how-can-i-use-r-tree-to-find-points-within-a-distance-in-spatialite

Looking around the docs a bit, the functions that MyIsam provides don't seem to have a good way to do that.

Comment: Are you trying to say that I should move to mongodb because it's absolutely important for my application to be able to do spatial search.

Comment: http://blog.opengeo.org/2011/09/28/indexed-nearest-neighbour-search-in-postgis/

I would move to PostGIS. It seems to directly support the functionality that you need.

Hope this helps. I'm not really familiar with GIS stuff, this is all the result of searching about.